# Any way to check for un-handled errors in a Go program?

Tags: go

Consider the following:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func foo() error {
    return errors.New("Danger!")
}

func main() {
    foo();
    fmt.Println("I don't have a care in the world!")
}
```

It would be nice if there was an easy way to see that possible errors from foo() are not being handled. Does Go have a built-in way to check programs/source files for errors that nothing has been done with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go does not have a built-in way to do that, but there's [a third-party tool](https://github.com/kisielk/errcheck/) by Kamil Kisiel that does. Just `go get github.com/kisielk/errcheck` then run `bin/errcheck your/import/path` from your `$GOPATH` and it will spit out a list of calls with ignored errors. (I just tried it on a project and, hrm, perhaps I'm not as 100% reliable about it as I thought.)

If you like it, you might also like [go vet](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/vet)'s checks, and [the lint package](https://github.com/golang/lint) used within Google for style checks.

Comment: Actually, bin/errcheck should never be under $GOROOT. It should be under $GOPATH.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [errcheck](https://github.com/kisielk/errcheck):

```
$ errcheck github.com/your/package
```

It will let you know when you are ignoring returned errors. I would argue that this should mostly be rare if you are using a decent editor (that shows you function signatures).